# MongoDB performance problems in Unity Game

Tags: c#, mongodb, performance, linq, unity-game-engine

We are decided to use mongo db in our game for real time database but the performance of the search result is not acceptable. These are the test result with 15.000 documents and 17 fields(strings, int,float)

```
   // 14000 ms 
    MongoUrl url = new MongoUrl("url-adress");
    MongoClient client = new MongoClient(url);
    var server = client.GetServer();
    var db = server.GetDatabase("myDatabase");
    var collection = db.GetCollection<PlayerFields>("Player");

    var ranks = collection.FindAll().AsQueryable().OrderByDescending(p=>p.Score).ToList().FindIndex(FindPlayer).Count();
```

This one is the worst. //.ToList() is for testing purposes. Don't use in production code.

Second test

```
        //9000 ms
        var ranks = collection.FindAll().AsQueryable().Where(p=>p.Score < PlayerInfos.Score).Count();
```

Third test

```
//2000 ms
var qq = Query. GT("Kupa", player.Score);
    var ranks = collection.Find( qq ).Where(pa=>(pa.Win + pa.Lose + pa.Draw) != 0 );
```

Is there any other way to make fast searches in mongo with C# .Net 2.0. We want to get player's rank according to users score and rank them.

Comment: I am not skilled in this part about DB, but maybe using an API that gives you this information ? So, you only make a call to a page and the server fetches that.

Comment: Can you supply your collection indexes? It may help with diagnosing the problem

Comment: Only 1 index  which is the ObjectId fields.

Comment: Hey if possible try using redis for your requirement as its more appropriate for your requirement, i am suggesting it as an alternate am suggesting it in addition to make process fast

Comment: @abhi thanks for your advice. I will look at it.

Comment: wouldn't you just use firebase ?

Comment: Before mongo we try to use firebase but it is in beta for C#. It doesn't fit our needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To caveat this, I've not been a .NET dev for a few years now, so if there is a problem with the c# driver then I can't really comment, but I've got a good knowledge of Mongo so hopefully I'll help...

**Indexes**

Indexes will help you out a lot here. As you are ordering and filtering on fields which aren't indexed, this will only cause you problems as the database gets larger.

Indexes are direction specific (ascending/descending). Meaning that your "Score" field should be indexed descending:

```
db.player.ensureIndex({'Score': -1}) // -1 indicating descending
```

**Queries**

Also, Mongo is really awesome (in my opinion) and it doesn't look like you're using it to be best of it's abilities.

Your first call:

```
var ranks = collection.FindAll().AsQueryable().OrderByDescending(p=>p.Score).ToList().FindIndex(FindPlayer).Count();
```

It appears (this is where my .NET knowledge may be letting me down) that you're retrieving the entire collection `ToList()`, then filtering it in memory (`FindPlayer predicate`) in order to retrieve a subset of data. I believe that this will be evaluating the entire curser (15.000 documents) into the memory of your application.

You should update your query so that Mongo is doing the work rather than your application.

Given your other queries are filtering on `Score`, adding the index as described above should drastically increase the performance of these other queries

**Profiling**

If the call that you're expecting to make when run from the mongo cli is behaving as expected, it could be that the driver is making slightly different queries.

In the mongo CLI, you will first need to set the profiling:

```
db.setProfilingLevel(2)
```

You can then query the profile collection to see what queries are actually being made:

```
db.system.profile.find().limit(5).sort({ts: -1}).pretty()
```

This will show you the 5 most recent calls.

Comment: As soon as you call .ToList() it will evalulate any lazy loading item in memory, so I think your assumptions are correct

Comment: @justcompile Yes your are right. We don't use .ToList() in production code it is only for testing purpose. After creating an index to score will i call the same query with third way ?

Comment: I just create indexes and try to find query like this  var pla = Query.EQ("UserID", PlayerInfos.userID);
  PlayerFields rPlayer = playerData.PlayerInfo.Find(new QueryDocument("UserID", PlayerInfos.userID)).First(); but it excited 5000ms. I don't understand what is going on with mongodb. These return times is very slow !!

Comment: Have you tried to run the queries against mongo directly? If you can debug the call using the 'explain' method on cursors to find out how your query is performing. e.g db.player.find({userid: 123}).explain(true) it will tell you if an index is being used amongst other useful things

Comment: @justcompile When I try to getIndex, successfully return the index I created before. but in explain log indexFilterSet: false. In mongo its self everything works fine...

Comment: It might be worth turning mongo profiling on to be able to find what queries are actually being made by the driver. I will update my answer to include some pointers

Comment: @justcompile thanks for your answer. when I debug with explain(true) log msj show executionTimeInMills 10-50ms. I call these methods in main thread although execution time is fast these calls kill main thread. I think there is no problem in mongo. Should I put mongo call to another thread ?